How to get primary color from the theme of a flutter app
I have a problem with theming a flutter app. I cannot get the primary color from of the theme. Here is the example code
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
          primary: Colors.blue,
          secondary: Colors.amber,
        ),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: const ColorScheme.dark(
          primary: Colors.grey,
          secondary: Colors.white,
        ),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            child: Container(
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I want the container to have the primary color of the theme which is blue in light mode and grey in dark mode. But It always shows purple color in both light and dark mode
Light Mode

Dark Mode

I have tried different solution many times. But result is same. I am new to flutter. I hope a kind reply.
Thank you.

As you are accessing color from same page, try to create object of color and use that object in your container. Color primaryColor = Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary. This is likely due to the use of the Theme.of(context) method in the build method of MyApp, where the context is not yet fully aware of the theme settings.

@DroidFlutter Thanks for your reply. I tried that too. but it doesn't work

Try to create StatelessWidget with the same page and same container and create object of color and try again.

Another way is wrap Container with Builder and there you can initial color variable and use it.

@DroidFlutter It is working now by wrapping container with the builder. Thanks for your help.

modify to this for most simple
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
          primary: Colors.blue,
          secondary: Colors.amber,
          primaryContainer: Colors.blue,
        ),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: const ColorScheme.dark(
          primary: Colors.grey,
          secondary: Colors.white,
        ),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Builder(builder: (context) {
          return Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              child: Container(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

the context is not yet aware of the changes in theme

Thanks for your reply. This solution has worked

pasanmaduranga, Well done on starting!
Try to first centralize your themeData in a seperate file and just calling that. You can use a class with static variables.
Centralizing texts (strings), colors, and theme data makes it easier to edit in the long run of the project or program.
theme.dart file:
class AppTheme {
    /// Customize as needed
    /* --- Light Theme ---*/
    static ThemeData ligthTheme = ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        primaryColor: Colors.blue,
        )

    /* --- Dark Theme ---*/
    static ThemeData darkTheme  = ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primaryColor: Colors.grey,
    )
}

Usage:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'theme.dart'; /// Import the theme file

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: AppTheme.lightTheme, /// Assign Light Theme
      darkTheme: AppTheme.darkTheme, /// Assign Dark Theme
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            child: Container(
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Back to your question:
You were close by using the Theme.of(context), as Theme.of(context) allows you to access the currently active theme on the app by the Buildcontext, context.
You just need to use:
Theme.of(context).primaryColor

It will retrieve the current primary color available in the themeData based on the context.
Meaning, if its lightmode, it will return the light mode's primary color and vice versa.
So in your case:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
          primary: Colors.blue,
          secondary: Colors.amber,
        ),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: const ColorScheme.dark(
          primary: Colors.grey,
          secondary: Colors.white,
        ),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            child: Container(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, /// Changed to .primaryColor
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Happy coding pasanmaduranga!!!

Thank you for your reply. I tried this solution too. But unfortunately result is same. I couldn't figure out where that purple color comes from.

Try defining it as a standalone property rather than in the colorscheme prop. So ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.blue). You can then try to access it with Theme.of(context).primaryColor. pasanmaduranga
